# how to find id of array element from element text/value

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, getelementbyid

I have the following code. In the alert(text) line I get which elements are in the array. I need to figure out id of the span for that element. For example for the second element in the array, I need to figure out that the id for Yellow is "test4", so I can determine that the ids of the elements in the array are, test2, test4 and test6. I can't figure out how to get the span id from the text/value in the span.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function doFunction(){
    var myArray = ["Green", "Yellow", "Brown"];
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 
    text = myArray[i];
    alert(text);
    }
    }
    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="test1">Red</span><br>
    <span id="test2">Green</span><br>
    <span id="test3">Blue</span><br>
    <span id="test4">Yellow</span><br>
    <span id="test5">Orange</span><br>
    <span id="test6">Brown</span><br>
<button name="button" onclick="doFunction()">Click Me</button>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although I've answered your *literal* question below, I can't help but think if we had a broader view of what you were trying to achieve, we could help you find a better overall way to do it.

Comment: Why do you need to get the id of the "yellow" color, why dont you put the color as the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function doFunction(){
var myArray = ["Green", "Yellow", "Brown"];
var mySpans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < mySpans.length; i++) { 
       if(myArray.indexOf(mySpans[i].innerHTML) > -1){
           alert(mySpans[i].id);
       }
   }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4rZ5h/

This uses [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), so you'll need a shiv for IE<9 support

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  Even though the first response was also the answer, I am going to mark this as the answer because people new to javascript will have the alert with the span id.

Answer (score 0):

Your only real option is to first get a list of the spans, for instance from `querySelectorAll`, then loop through that list looking at the `innerHTML` of each to see which one(s) match.

For instance, you can get the list like this:

```
// Find all spans with `id` values starting with "test"
var list = document.querySelectorAll("span[id^=test]");
```

(There I'm using the "attribute starts with" selector, but if I were you I'd add a class to the spans and use that instead.)

Then loop through that list (inside your loop through the values in your array).

```
var listIndex;
for (listIndex = 0; listIndex < list.length; ++listIndex) {
    if (text === list[listIndex].innerHTML) {
        // it matches
    }
}
```

So putting all that together:

```
function doFunction(){
    var myArray = ["Green", "Yellow", "Brown"];
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("span[id^=test]");
    var listIndex, text, i;
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 
        text = myArray[i];
        for (listIndex = 0; listIndex < list.length; ++listIndex) {
            if (text === list[listIndex].innerHTML) {
                // this span matches
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Side note: If you look above, you'll notice I added `var` statements for `i` and `text`. Without them, you were falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), which is best avoided.

Comment: var el = document.getElementsByClassName('spanner').innerHTML;
alert("el is: " + el);

Comment: Excellent! Thank You soo much!  I really appreciate the detail and explanation your code worked perfectly.  I wasted many hours trying to figure this out and I learned from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through each span to see if they are in your array, and if they are, alert their ID.

```
function doFunction(){
    var myArray = ["Green", "Yellow", "Brown"];

    // All your spans
    var mySpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    // Go through each of them
    for (var i = 0; i < mySpans.length; i++) {
        // See if the value is in the array
        var myIndex = myArray.indexOf(mySpans[i].innerHTML);
        // If they are
        if(myIndex!=-1){
           // Alert the text and the id
           alert(myArray[myIndex] + ' : ' + mySpans[i].getAttribute('id'));
        }
    }
}
```

#### JS Fiddle